# Is it possible to implement an Insertion Sort algorithm with a given user input without knowing it's size in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, user-input

I want to implement an Insertion Sort Algorithm with given user input array (with integers) without knowing it's size.
It should basicly run like that:

```
Enter the numbers: 1,2,3,7,79,9 (user input)

Sorted form is: 1,2,3,7,9,79
```

Is there any way to do it? I saw many examples but all these were asking the size of the array.

Comment: But you do know the size, it's the number of inputs.

Comment: True. But what do i mean is, i do not know the size at the beginning. Normally it says first "Enter amount of the elements" like int that page: https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-insertion-sort/ But i do not want to give the size of array.

Comment: Use an ArrayList instead of an array.

Comment: You don't have to enter the size. Instead, ask the user for one string input. For example: "1 2 3 7 79 9". Then, you can split the string by spaces and cast each token to integer.

Comment: *"Is there any way to do it?" **Yes.** --- Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the user inputs numbers in the form "1,2,3,7,79,9", you can convert that into an array of the proper length using

```
String[] stringArr = userInput.split(",");
```

Then you can create an integer array of the same length

```
int[] nums = new int[stringArr.length];
```

then cast each of the string values to integers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[i]);
}
```

Now you have an int array ready to be sorted.  This works for user input of any length (even zero!)